# How to replace a text using CSS and hover?

Tags: html, css

I know there seems to be a lot of questions like this but they all seem to do something slightly different than what I have.  Most just ADD text.  I have some CSS that does that already, what I'm trying to do is modify what I got to have text ALREADY there that gets replaced.  I just can't seem to wrap my brain around this/can't make the right connections to make it work without breaking something else.

Right now, if you hover over the picture, the whole picture gets partially whited-out and text appears.  This works exactly how I need it.  What I can't figure out is how to ADD text that is there BEFORE and disappears AFTER.

I saw this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d64A9/ but I can't grasp how to apply that (if it's even the right thing to do).

Here is what I got:

**CSS**

```
.pic2 {  
    height: 125px; 
    background: url(http://somewebsite/somepic.jpg) no-repeat; 
    background-size: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
} 

.text2 {  
    height: 125px;
    background: #FFF;
    opacity: 0;
} 

h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.pic2:hover .text2 { 
    opacity: 0.6; 
    text-align: center; 
    color: #000000; 
    font-size: 20px; 
    font-weight: 700; 
    font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    padding: 30px; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://somewebsite/page" style="text-decoration: none;">
    <div class="pic2">
        <div class="text2"> 
            <h1>Private</h1>
            <br />
            Personal information and requirements are kept completely confidential.
        </div> 
    </div> 
</a>
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Bhojendra: read the second paragraph :)

Answer (score 1):

In the fiddle you posted, the original text is made invisible by settings its font-size to 0, and content is loaded into a pseudo element from the html data-attribute. Both happens on hover. Have a look at the comments:

```
span:hover{
  font-size: 0; /* set the font size to 0 to make the original text invisible */
}

span:hover:before{ /* create pseudo element */
  font-size: initial; /* don't apply font-size: 0 here*/
  content: attr(data-hovertext); /* get the data-attribute value */
}
```

To apply this, you need to add your data-attribute to the markup:

```
<span data-hovertext="This text will replace the other text">Personal information and requirements are kept completely confidential.</span>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/::after for more :)

Comment: Excellent!  Exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks sd!  (I can't upvote yet, but consider this an upvote!)  Now this covers one part.  Let's see if I can get it to look pretty for the whole of the image.)

Answer (score 0):

Or this way:
HTML:

```
<a href="target" data-hovertext="Hover Text">Normal Text</a>
```

CSS:

```
 a:hover {font-size: 0;}
 a:hover:before {font-size: initial;content: 'I think more browsers would support this solution';}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnxnhn9b/) for you.

Comment: Nope, bad idea. You should keep content out of your CSS, always! And browser support is really good: http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset ;)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for that info, I will keep that in mind if I need to use that in future.

Answer (score 0):

Now it is only possible with Js not Css

```js
var anchor;

anchor = document.querySelector("a[data-hovertext]");
anchor.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver, false);
anchor.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseoOut, false);

function mouseOver()
{  
    anchor.innerHTML = this.getAttribute("data-hovertext")
}

function mouseoOut()
{  
   anchor.innerHTML = "Normal Text"
}
```

```html
<a href="target" data-hovertext="Hover Text">Normal Text</a>
```